# Tomcat Timeout?

Tags: jsp, ms-access, tomcat

What would make a JSP not finish running and not throw an error?

I have a JSP that queries an MS Access database, which is a very slow process (we're hopefully going to be using an Oracle database soon). But this code I've been using has always finished executing before.In addition, the page is displaying information that is in the page well after the connection the database is closed.

After it takes the information from the database it puts that information in some beans that I've written for this app. The beans have been working normally in a nearly identical set of code in a different JSP.

It then iterates through the list made of the data (a list of 35 items, which is the count it gives me when I have it display the size of the results) and displays data from up to 10 rows that meet certain criteria. It does fine through 15 iterations then stops without any  error (showing 5 of the 23 records that meet the criteria). Then it just stops. No error, nothing else. It just shows me the output line at the end of the loop then stops.

Is there a timeout setting in Tomcat that I can extend? And if there is, does the timeout record an error?

Comment: Used a debugger? The likely cause is a deadlock. Is your code thread-safe.

Comment: thanks pyroscope, but before I looked back here I found my issue.

I was trying to use a property from an old version of a bean -- a property that isn't in that bean anymore. Well, yeah, of course that'll screw things up. 

Time from actually checking the logs to testing the fix: 2 minutes. 

I can be such a doofus.

Comment: @The E: Please make sure to close the question or provide your answer and accept it... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to use a property from an old version of a bean -- a property that isn't in that bean anymore. Well, yeah, of course that'll screw things up. Time from actually checking the logs to testing the fix: 2 minutes. I can be such a doofus